# MySQL 5.7 on Amazon Aurora - how to read the IO Cache vs. Disk Read metric?

Tags: query-performance, mysql-5.7, configuration, performance-tuning, aws-aurora

I'm trying to determine how often InnoDB is hitting RAM vs. disk.

Does `db.Cache.innoDB_buffer_pool_hits.avg` mean InnoDB went to the buffer pool?

Does `db.Cache.Innodb_buffer_pool_reads.avg` mean that InnoDB had to go to disk?

Is that a good metric to use for determining RAM vs. disk?

Here's how my DB looked over one week.

[image]

[image]